# Hostapd failed to start - Failed to initialize interface

Tags: linux-networking, hostapd, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to set up hostapd on linux machine as a network authenticator with 802.1x.

I've been mostly following [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/assembly_setting-up-an-802-1x-network-authentication-service-for-lan-clients-using-hostapd-with-freeradius-backend_configuring-and-managing-networking) guide, with some adaptations since I'm using Ubuntu Jammy instead of RHEL, and using veth interfaces in the bridge instead of physical ones.

I created the hostapd.conf file as instructed with the [content](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/assembly_setting-up-an-802-1x-network-authentication-service-for-lan-clients-using-hostapd-with-freeradius-backend_configuring-and-managing-networking#:%7E:text=Create%20the%20/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf%20file%20with%20the%20following%20content%3A) as they described - My bridge interface is br0 like in the sample, I changed the *own_ip_addr* to the IP on interface br0, and changed the *nas_identifier*, *auth_server_addr*, *auth_server_shared_secret*, *acct_server_addr*, and *acct_server_shared_secret* to match the config on my RADIUS server.

Everything else is the same as the example file, but for some reason hostapd wont start. /var/log/syslog says there is an error in the config file but doesn't really explain what the problem is:

```
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 320.
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox hostapd[347060]: 1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox hostapd[347060]: Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox hostapd[347060]: Failed to initialize interface
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 25 13:47:13 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 321.
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox hostapd[347062]: 1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox hostapd[347062]: Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox hostapd[347062]: Failed to initialize interface
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 25 13:47:15 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 322.
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox hostapd[347065]: 1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox hostapd[347065]: Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox hostapd[347065]: Failed to initialize interface
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 25 13:47:17 blackfox systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: You could start hostapd manually in foreground and "even" more debugs (-dd).

Comment: If you want to put this as an answer I'll accept it. Doing that gave me this output:
random: getrandom() support available
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Line 6: Invalid group 'wheel'
1 errors found in configuration file '/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf'
Failed to set up interface with /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
hostapd_init: free iface 0x56141e09ca00
Failed to initialize interface
From there I read up on the ctrl_interface_group parameter and realized group 'wheel' doesn't exist. Set it to root and it started successfully.

Comment: Glad you found the error but I wouldn't put my basic comment as answer. You can still answer it yourself if you think that will further help people or simply delete the question if you prefer.

Comment: I'll leave it up in case it helps anyone else, thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

Gave some more details as to what was going on. RHEL has a special administrative group called **wheel** which is non-existent in Ubuntu.

Went back to the config file and changed

```
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
```

to replace **wheel** with either 0, root, 27, sudo

It started successfully with all of them.